# Where should I specify my charset if not on a meta element?

Tags: html, validation

I'm getting an HTML validation error for the following line, I'm not sure where I should specify my charset if I don't do it within the meta tag.

```
Line 5, Column 70: Attribute charset not allowed on element meta at this point.

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8"/>
```

Comment: Note the metatag you've got there would be fine if `charset` was inside the `content` attribute like so: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because you put it in a `Content-type` meta tag, this is not allowed.

simply make a seperate meta tag, e.g.

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

this should validate for you.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. You should use    as this is recommended in html5 and it is a new recommendation.

Below is a simple html5 layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
<meta charset="UTF-8"> 
<title>Title of the document</title> 
</head>

<body> 
Content of the document...... 
</body>

</html>
```